VIM Grep recursive search
├───Home
│   ├───Shared Library
│   └───Src
│       ├───module 1
│       ├───module 2

Above is my folder structure. If I call vimgrep from the home folder, all the directories below are included in the search.
:vimgrep /Pattern/ **/*.c

Suppose if I do a vim search in any of the below directories such src or shared_lib, only those directories and directories below are included in the search.
How to specify the path for vimgrep so as to include folders that are outside the current directory?
PS: I am new to vim and learning this awesome tool now. so please bear if this question is too amateurish

If you're in src, did you try :vimgrep /Pattern/ ../**/*.c?

@ggorlen -thankyou,  yes your suggestion worked, i had misunderstood ** --> indicated current directly and was try ** for other folders

@ggorlen - suggestion worked, i had mis interpreted the ** as the path specifier
just adding "../" - the no of the times to point out the root folder resolves the issue
